# Titanium Geolocation Not Working in Android Emulator

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I get this error:

> [ERROR][GeolocationModule(  278)] (KrollRuntimeThread) [633,2564] Unable to get current position, location is null

and I have followed other people's advice without any luck.

Could someone lead me in the right direction?  I would be so grateful.  Thank you!

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title : 'map_landing',
    backgroundColor : '#fff'
});

var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title : 'hails_window',
    backgroundColor : '#fff'
});

var win3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title : 'cabs_window',
    backgroundColor : '#fff'
});

User = {
    location : {}
};

var hail_button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Hail Cab',
    top : 10,
    width : 200,
    height : 50
});

var find_button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Find People',
    bottom : 10,
    width : 200,
    height : 50
});

var options = {
    accessKeyId : '',
    secretAccessKey : ''
}

Ti.Geolocation.purpose = "Receive user location";

Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    if (e.error) {
        alert('HFL cannot get your current location');
        return;
    }

    User.location.longitude = e.coords.longitude;
    User.location.latitude = e.coords.latitude;
    User.location.accuracy = e.coords.accuracy;
    User.location.speed = e.coords.speed;
    User.location.timestamp = e.coords.timestamp;

    var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
        mapType : Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
        region : {
            latitude : User.location.latitude,
            longitude : User.location.longitude,
            latitudeDelta : 0.01,
            longitudeDelta : 0.01
        },
        animate : true,
        regionFit : true,
        userLocation : true
    });

    win1.add(mapview);
    win1.add(hail_button);
    win1.add(find_button);
    hail_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert('hello');
        $.ajax('http://hail.pagodabox.com/add_hail', {
            type : 'POST',
            lat : User.location.latitude,
            lang : User.location.longitude,
            success : function(response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        })
    });

    find_button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    });
    win1.open();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the emulator's position correctly using DDMS? (Demonstrate in the question how you're doing this.) What versions of the Titanium SDK and the Android Emulator are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to track this down, but I think I've found the steps needed to "fix" the lack of a location in the Android emulator (from [this answer](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/5291/tips-and-tricks-mobile---thread-to-share-some-experience-that-may-help-the-others#answer-105071)):

> First, open ddms (Dalvik Debug Monitor). On Windows, navigate to the
>   android-sdk\tools directory and run ddms.bat. The first line in the
>   top-left pane will read something like "emulator-####" such as
>   emulator-5560.
>
> Open a command prompt window. Enter 'telnet localhost ####'
>   substituting the number you found above. This will open a telnet
>   window to your android emulator.
>
> Enter the following command (substitute your own longitude & latitude,
>   in that order, if you'd like):
>
> `geo fix -82.411629 28.054553`
>
> (I'm pretty sure you can add elevation as a third number.) The GPS
>   icon will appear in the emulator's notification bar. Geolocation is
>   now available. At this point, I could get location data in my app and
>   in other apps, such as Maps.