# How to get Current location using MapModule?

Tags: javascript, ios, location, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to get my current location but I don't know the right code, can anyone help me? This is my code below:

```
var MapModule = require('ti.map');

var vc = MapModule.createAnnotation({

 title: 'You are Here',
 //subtitle: 'Sao Paulo, SP',
 pincolor: MapModule.ANNOTATION_GREEN,
 image:"/ui/images/you.png",

});

var walmart = MapModule.createAnnotation({

 latitude: -23.474891,
 longitude: -46.526756,
 title: 'Wallmart',
 subtitle: 'Guarulhos, SP',
 pincolor: MapModule.ANNOTATION_RED,
 image:"/ui/images/buscador_walmart.png",

}); 

var mapview = MapModule.createView({

top:0,
height: "80%",
mapType: MapModule.NORMAL_TYPE,
region: {latitude: win.latitude, longitude: win.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001},
annotations: [vc,walmart],
animate:true,

});

mapview.visible = false;

win.add(mapview);
```

I also put **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** and **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** in **tiapp.xml** to request access the location.

anyone knows the right code to get my current location?

Comment: Now my project is send me "HFL cannot get your current location".

Comment: Are you testing in the Android emulator? If yes check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146510/titanium-geolocation-not-working-in-android-emulator

Comment: Robin, I'm testing on iOS... i don't know why isn't work

Comment: Hi Leonardo, I always face problems with iOS Simulator geolocation. Sometimes works, sometimes not. Try to change simulator, clean project, reinstall the app or reset the simulator.
Anyway, this is the code I'm using and it works:
`
if(Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled){
        Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleCurrentPosition);
}
`

And the handleCurrentPosition:
`
if(e.error){
  alert('Erro ao pegar posicao atual');
  console.log(e.error);
 }else{
  lat = e.coords.latitude;
                lng = e.coords.longitude;
 }
`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var onGetPositionError = function() {

    log('onGetPositionError');

    var lat = 52.3702157;
    var lon = 4.8951679;

    currentMapLat_ = lat;
    currentMapLon_ = lon;

    log('lat = ' +  lat + ' lon = ' + lon);

    $.mapView.setRegion({
        latitude: lat, longitude: lon,
        latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005
    });
};

var onGotPosition = function(e) {

    log('onGotPosition');

    var lon = e.coords.longitude;
    var lat = e.coords.latitude;

    currentMapLat_ = lat;
    currentMapLon_ = lon;

    log('lat = ' +  lat + ' lon = ' + lon);

    $.mapView.setRegion({
        latitude: lat, longitude: lon,
        latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005
    });
};

var getPosition = function() {
    Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
        if (e.error) {
            log(JSON.stringify(e));
            log('Cannot get current position');
            onGetPositionError();
            return;
        } else {
            onGotPosition(e);
            return;
        }
    });
};

$.locate.addEventListener('click', getPosition);
```

Comment: That's what I suggested, but sometimes the iOS simulator does not send the position =/
On device is working perfectly!

Comment: Hi Frank and Carlos! Please, take a look in this link [link]http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100176/current-location-não-funciona-com-mapmodule[/link] these are my codes! I wrote your code in my "geolocation.js" but I have to know what code I change in my "maps.js". I got the message = "Can't find variable: lat"; or "Can't find variable: currentMapLat_" Can you help me?